# Loop through multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I've found [this](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/06/c_c_tip_how_loop_through_multi_dimensional_arrays_quickly) article on how to loop through multi-dimensional arrays quickly.

I am using `Method 6: Nested loops with linear array and single incrementing index.`

It says `Method 8: Single loop with linear array and incrementing index` is faster, but I require nested loops indexes as well. When I try to calculate the nested loops indexes via if clauses, my code slows down (at least worst than nested loop approach).

Can you recommend anything for calculating individual indexes?

```
 int x1=0,x2=0; 
  for (int i1 = 1; i1 <= 10000; i1++){
             for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){

            x1++;
            if(x1>=100){
                x1=0;
                x2++;
             }

             if (x1 > 10)
             {
                 a[i] += a[i - 10*1];
             }
             if (x2 < 95)
             {
                 a[i] += a[i + 5*100];
             }
         }
     }
```

For  multidimensional array structure `a[x1][x2]`. I want to calculate 
`a[x1][x2]=a[x1-10][x2]+a[x1][x2+5]` which `a[x1][x2]` is converted to `a[x1+x2*100]`

[Program code](http://ideone.com/oKVdQI)

```
 method 8: 462 ns
method 6 297 ns
```

Is there a way I can improve this code in terms of speed?

Comment: You could split it into multiple threads to cover a section of the `a` array at a time. You will need to be very very careful for thread races though. And time it because thread creation overhead might make your problem worse. Alternatively, get a faster computer.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, for the next project may be:)

Comment: your array is a 100x100 matrix?

Comment: yes i make index math to convert into one dimensional array

Comment: and what value does the first 10 rows and last 5 columns have?

Comment: in the program code you can see it. the initialization is done by random number generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong index, it should be `a[ROWS][COLS]` and the index `i = row * COLS + col`.
Then you don't need the `if`s in the inner loop, you can write it like this:

```
double *v = a + 1000;    // destination
double *c = a;           // source is 10 rows before, using another pointer
                         // to take advantage of proximity in cache
for( x1 = 10; x1 < 100; x1++ ) {
    for( int x2 = 0; x2 < 95; x2++) {
        *v += *c + *(v + 5);
        ++v;
        ++c;
    }
    v += 5;  // skip the last 5 columns
    c += 5;
}
```

This give me a result of ~130 using the on line compiler at the link you posted

Comment: this code gives wrong results but i get the gist, thanks this was the most helpful comment thus far.

Comment: @EsraKaya the wrong result is caused probably by the `+=`. I followed your code, but you probably wanted a simple `=` and maybe to start from the bottom as we are changing the rows during the loop. If your goal was to "rotate" the columns and the rows, the code should be different.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, your avoid the two loops by doing its computation yourself which is certainly less efficient than what compiler can do. I would suggest you to keep two loops but spliting the loops to avoid conditions in them so that compiler can transform it to SIMD code.

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<95; j++) {
        a[i * 100 + j] = a[i *100 + j + 5] 
    }
}
for(int i=10; i<100; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<95; j++) {
        a[i * 100 + j] = a[(i - 10) * 100 + j] + a[i *100 + j + 5] 
    }
}
for(int i=10; i<100; i++) {
    for(int j=95; j<100; j++) {
        a[i * 100 + j] = a[(i - 10) * 100 + j]
    }
}
```

Your code will be easier to read.

I didn't test it here but for bigger matrix, performance can be improved thantks to cache locality. Looking at your code, you may use tiling to do it.

Comment: you are right about readibility, but calculating indexes slows the program run time. i will look up for tiling. thanks for suggestion